# How to order results by an existing boolean attribute first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many records with a `featured?` attribute.

I would like to query all, group them in featured and non-featured and if possible random them in between their groups (random and show the featured ones, then random the rest).

Any idea how to do this on ActiveRecord?

Comment: I think you might be able to first Order the list by Rand() to randomize the list then order it by featured attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`rand()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-rand-function.htm)

MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME> ORDER BY featured?, rand()
```

RAILS 3

```
ModelName.order("featured, rand()")
```

For Ex:-

```
id    featured
1      true
2      false
3      false
4      true
5      false
6      true
```

i want all the featured with value true first and then false, however order of the records withing the true and false group should be random

So my code will be

```
User.order("featured DESC, rand()")
```

and generated o/p is (Note:- order of the records between the group true/false can be changed)

```
id    featured
4      true
6      true
1      true
5      false
3      false
2      false
```

Comment: I don't see how your sample `order("featured?, rand()")` can work. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: check my edited answer also don't use column that ends with `?` ref :- https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/490

Comment: `User.order("featured, rand()")` is not returning the true`s first and the fatest after. Actually `User.order("featured, rand()").first` returns an object with `featured? false`.

Comment: use `DESC` in that case `User.order("featured DESC, rand()")`

Comment: Still not working for me. `Dvd.order("featured DESC, random()").first` is returning an object with `featured: false`.