# Index ordering not changing after .order field is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A little background: this is an app designed for managing a dog kennel, so you can `check-in` a patient and `check-out`. Upon `check-in` the `has_current_stay` field is updated to `true`, with the opposite occurring upon `check-out`.

So for my application I have a model of type `patient` with an `index` method in the controller as follows:

```
def index
    @patients = Patient.search(params[:search]).order(:has_current_stay)
    if @patients.count == 1
      redirect_to @patients.first
    end
end
```

The index work correctly until I `check-out` a patient, at which point they float to the top of the list again - even though their `has_current_stay` field should prevent them from being at the top. Do I need to somehow 'refresh' the index upon check-out?

FWIW: `check-out` is accomplished by calling `destroy` on the `stay` that the patient is associated with. Below is the `destroy` method in the `stays controller`.

```
  def destroy

    @stay = Stay.find(params[:id]).destroy

    @runn = Runn.find_by_id(@stay.runn_id)
    @runn.occupied = false
    @runn.save

    @patient = Patient.find(@stay.patient_id)
    @patient.has_current_stay = false
    @patient.save



    flash[:success] = "Checked out #{@patient.name}"
    redirect_to patients_url
  end
```

Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT: SQL query when `patients#index` is requested:

```
Started GET "/all_patients" for ::1 at 2016-04-25 15:26:04 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PatientsController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "patients"
  Rendered shared/_search_an_index.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Patient Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  ORDER BY "patients"."has_current_stay" DESC
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  Stay Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "stays".* FROM "stays" WHERE "stays"."patient_id" = $1  ORDER BY "stays"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["patient_id", 2]]
  Runn Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1  ORDER BY ident ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "stays".* FROM "stays" WHERE "stays"."patient_id" = $1  ORDER BY "stays"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["patient_id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1  ORDER BY ident ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Stay Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "stays".* FROM "stays" WHERE "stays"."patient_id" = $1  ORDER BY "stays"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["patient_id", 35]]
  Runn Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1  ORDER BY ident ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "stays".* FROM "stays" WHERE "stays"."patient_id" = $1  ORDER BY "stays"."id" DESC LIMIT 1  [["patient_id", 35]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "runns".* FROM "runns" WHERE "runns"."id" = $1  ORDER BY ident ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  Rendered patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application (158.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 643ms (Views: 560.0ms | ActiveRecord: 18.5ms)
```

Comment: Is any ordering used in the `Patient.search` scope? Do you perhaps use ordering in a default scope in the `Patient` model? Because if not, I would expect Anthony's answer to work. Can you show us the SQL query that gets run when the search is made in the `index` action?

Comment: I don't know why your desc ordering wont work, here is the similar sample where order works well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524311/how-to-order-results-by-an-existing-boolean-attribute-first

Comment: @BoraMa I've appended my SQL query

Comment: That is weird, it should work. Can you run the query `SELECT "patients".* FROM "patients"  ORDER BY "patients"."has_current_stay" DESC` manually in your db console and see (show) the result?

Comment: When I do that it lists all of the `patients` that have `has_current_stay=false` AND have never been check-in first. Next are the `patients` that have `has_current_stay=true`. Finally are the `patients` that have `has_current_stay=false` AND have been checked-in and checked-out. Mind boggling indeed.

Comment: I would paste the result but it's very messy.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `has_current_stay` is indeed never nil? What data type is this column? Can you show it's line in `schema.rb`?

Comment: `t.boolean  "has_current_stay"` is the line in `schema.rb`. 
on each of the `patients` `show` we list the boolean value, and it indeed reads as either `true` or `false` for every patient.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to migrate that column to `t.boolean "has_current_stay", default: false, null: false`? Just to make sure... Cause the ordering behavior that you describe still suggests there are some nils, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

`.order(:has_current_stay)` is doing an ascending sort on a boolean field. Since you're setting `@patient.has_current_stay = false`, this would effectively bring it to the top of the list since `false` acts like a zero value.

Try doing a descending sort: `order(has_current_stay: :desc)` to keep users with a false value for `has_current_stay` at the bottom.

Comment: `order(has_current_stay: :desc)` actually floats people _with_  `has_current_stay=true` to the bottom of the list, and then floats people who  WERE checked in and then checked out below them - so essentially the OPPOSITE of what I had before.

Comment: Is `has_current_stay` nil for some users? Can you elaborate on what you want the sorted result to be?

Comment: `has_current_stay` is never nil, it is either `false` or `true`. I want the sorted result to be --> `has_current_stay=true` on top of the list, and `has_current_stay=false` underneath it - simple as that.